# Why should I add return false in Phonegap(jquery ajax)?

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, adt

I don't understand the purpose of 'return false'.
I want to know why can't I see the pop-up message If I don't add 'return false' in the end of the ajax function.
Can anyone tell me?
I am using adt+Phonegap under windows.

```
$("button").click(function() {
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert('ok');
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('false');
    }
  });
   return false;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return false;
```

It's equivalent to `event.stopPropagation` and `event.preventDefault()`  I think in your case, you are clicking an anchor tag or a submit button so you need to preventDefault() behaviour in order to let ajax request which is asynchron to finished. Otherwise, the default behaviour would refresh page or load an other one.

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery Events: Stop (Mis)Using Return False](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/), returning `false` performs three tasks when called:

1. `event.preventDefault();`
2. `event.stopPropagation();`
3. Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.